# Install protoc without maven (win7, java)

Tags: java, windows, protocol-buffers

I tried installing protoc on windows without maven (I can't download maven due to org firewall issues).
I have my `protoc.exe` in the `..\src` (not in `java\src` as many do) folder as mentioned in the readme.

When I give `protoc --version` in the command prompt, I get `libprotoc 2.6.0`. That's fine. 
But when I give `protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`, I get `missing input file` all the time & I can't proceed further.

I have tried giving the entire path where my `descriptor.proto` lies, tried changing `-I` to `-IPATH`, tried using `--proto_path` but I still get the same `Missing input file` error.

Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want (from the Protobuf-Java readme) is:

```
protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

Notice that the `-I` flag and the `descriptor.proto` argument are two different arguments. It looks like you accidentally merged them into one.

Comment: Thanks a ton Kenton! I was able to generate the bean class then and was happy with it. 

But now, I have another .proto file and I get "Missing output directives" this time around. Path is same as that in your reply but for the .proto filename.

Comment: "Missing output directives" means you forgot the `--java_out` flag.